# "blocking" is too generic

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[blocking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blocking) includes questions about all kinds of software and problems, from [Make computer lock itself after 30 minutes of continued usage](https://superuser.com/q/800804) to  [Block ONLY Google Ads](https://superuser.com/q/655016) and [Block outgoing connection to a specific ip address in Mac OSx](https://superuser.com/q/646466). I think it should be removed.

Comment: There's over 300 questions, and I suspect most would be appropriate to retag with something more specific.  Suggestions?

Comment: @fixer1234 I believe that the related tags (like [tag:networking] and [tag:firewall] should cover both incoming and outgoing traffic/data, shouldn't they? Why must we have specific tags for "blocking" and "allowing" things?

Comment: A certain level of granularity is needed, but ambiguous words, like "blocking", aren't the right ones.  "Networking" would be way too broad for a question about blocking anything.  A tag about blocking ads is pretty focused, and the kind of thing some people follow (attract answerers).  The subject of access control/computer locking probably merits a tag (and I'm guessing there already are some).  This might be a good candidate for culling; start thinning the list by retagging cases with obvious better exisitng tags.  Then it's easier to figure out what to do with the rest.